# Add-in silently fails to install on Mac Outlook

Tags: outlook, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an add-in for Outlook. My manifest installs without problems in Outlook for the web, but when I try to install the manifest in Outlook for Mac (v16.43), it appears to succeed, but after closing the add-ins window and re-opening it, the add-in has disappeared.

I have generated some logs from Outlook, and see this error:

```
04/12/2020 14:29:13 Unexpected  Manifest    Issue encountered while parsing manifest, 
add-in ID : <id>, Location : Error at element "Action" : 
Add-in manifest parsing encountered an unexpected child node, Line=90, CharPosition=16
```

The relevant parts of the manifest are below. The `Action` element referred to in the error is the one in the `MobileFormFactor` section. If I remove the `MobileFormFactor` section, then the manifest installs successfully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">

  ...

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Description resid="residDescription"></Description>
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets>
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.3"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="apptComposeGroup">
                  <Label resid="residDescription"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="insertMeetingButton">
                    <Label resid="addLabel"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="addLabel"/>
                      <Description resid="residTooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon-16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon-32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="48" resid="icon-48"/>
                      <bt:Image size="64" resid="icon-64"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon-80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="residTaskpaneUrl"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>

          <MobileFormFactor>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileOnlineMeetingCommandSurface">
              <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="insertMeetingButton">
                <Label resid="prodName"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="icon-grey16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="icon-grey16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="icon-grey16"/>

                  <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="icon-grey32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="icon-grey32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="icon-grey32"/>

                  <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="icon-grey48"/>
                  <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="icon-grey48"/>
                  <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="icon-grey48"/>
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                  <SourceLocation resid="residTaskpaneUrl"/>
                </Action>
              </Control>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </MobileFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>

    ...

    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: If see that in your manifest the following section is missing "<FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />"... try adding it and see if it helps.

Comment: In addition to the function file, for the [MobileOnlineMeetingCommandSurface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint#mobileonlinemeetingcommandsurface-preview) ExtensionPoint, the Action type should be different (see the linked doc for an example).